# How do I turn off django cumulus in my local_settings.py

Tags: django, cumulus

I have taken over a project that uses django cumulus for cloud storage. On my development machine, some times I use a slow internet connection, and every time I save a change, django recompiles and tries to make a connection to the racksapace store

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): identity.api.rackspacecloud.com
```

This sometimes takes 15 seconds and is a real pain. I read a post where someone said they turned off cumulus for local development. I think this was done by setting

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
```

but unfortunately the poster did not specify. If someone knows a simple setting I can put in my local settings to serve media and static files from my local machine and stop django trying to connect to my cloud storage on every save, that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant reloading of the rackspace bucket was because the previous developer had

```
from cumulus.storage import SwiftclientStorage
class PrivateStorage(SwiftclientStorage):
```

and in models.py

```
from common.storage import PrivateStorage
PRIVATE_STORE = PrivateStorage()
...
class Upload(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(storage=PRIVATE_STORE, upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

This meant *every* time the project reloaded, it would create a new https connection to rackspace, and time out if the connection was poor. I created a settings flag to control this by putting the import of SwiftclientStorage and defining of PrivateStorage like so

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.USECUMULUS:
    from cumulus.storage import SwiftclientStorage

    class PrivateStorage(SwiftclientStorage):
...
else:
    class PrivateStorage():
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it looks like you should just need the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` to be default value, which is `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage` according to the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py#L260).

However, a better approach would be to not set anything in your local settings and set the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` and `CUMULUS` in a `staging_settings.py` or `prod_settings.py` file.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but setting DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE to that value does not fix it, and if I remove the settings altogether for that and CUMULUS, I get authentication errors. It still tries to connect to the remote cloud storage. It does not seem be be a middle ware thing either :(